# Novel Identification Help--Aliens Eating The Locals

Tags: story-identification, novel, alien-invasion

I read the first book of a series years ago involving an alien fleet tearing through human worlds, conquering them and eating the population. Humanity puts together a large fleet and jumps through wormholes to fight them. It is driving me crazy, because I cannot remember the title.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/241563/can-you-help-me-locate-this-series-of-books (about the series as a whole)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like it could be "[In Death Ground](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/504380.In_Death_Ground)" by David Weber and Steven White from 1997 as part of the [StarFire Series](http://www.goodreads.com/series/41767-starfire).

Matches include:

1. Wormhole travel:

"A survey squadron travels through a previously uncharted warp point and encounters a hive-like species referred to derisively as the 'Bugs' "

2. Aliens tearing through human worlds

"the Bugs ambush the survey squadron, with a great loss of material and human life. Pursuing the survivors, the Bugs mount a massive invasion of Terran and Orion space."

3. To the comment below on the other answer. "The aliens were more spider-like."

"referred to derisively as the 'Bugs' (inspired by the Arachnids in Robert A. Heinlein's Starship Troopers)." The aliens are definitely spider-like in form.

4. Aliens eating humans:

"Satellites left behind monitor the conquered planets and **reveal that
Bugs regard other sentient life forms as food sources."

> indeed the Bugs prefer to consume their prey alive. It is later revealed that the Bugs raise ranches of conquered species.**

5. Humanity puts together a large fleet:

"The alternative being "equal opportunity genocide", Terrans, Orions,
Gorm, and Ophiuchi form a Grand Alliance, with Terrans and Orions as
the senior members. The novel features long and very detailed space
and ground battle sequences, detailed discussions of tactical
doctrine, the ongoing arms race between the Alliance and the Bugs, and
the development of interpersonal relations between military people of
different background and species."

A description of the book and series can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_Death_Ground):

[image: Wiki Image]

Answer (score 1):

You may be thinking of John Ringo's "A Hymn Before Battle". This was the first in a tetralogy about war with the Posleen.

[image]

Although humanity doesn't put together a fleet, it's provided by the Darhel (who are, in the long run, the bad guys). But the conquering and eating part fit, and it came out in 2001.

The others in the series are

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The Posleen are not what I was thinking of. The aliens were more spider-like and had a massive fleet that just overwhelmed the human fleet.