# Book about humanity and four other alien races at war, learn they are seed colonies of dead civilizations

Tags: story-identification, books, military-sf, space-opera

I'm looking for a book I read 6 or 7 years ago - maybe less.

Humanity is at war with one or more of four alien races, there is a sixth race which is a cross breed of the others. Humans come across one of the races and help them get into space or outer space. Can't remember much else apart from they find a message from their own civilizations many millennia in the past and realize that they were all transplanted to a new galaxy by their original civilizations at an almost non existent technological level due to a galactic war that devastated their original planets.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) and [edit] in anything else you may remember?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73774/novel-identification-help-aliens-eating-the-locals

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're describing the [*Starfire*](https://www.goodreads.com/series/41767-starfire) series, a collaboration by Steven White, David Weber, Shirley Meier, and Charles E. Gannon,

Some details that match your description: Multiple star-faring cultures, the impending invasion by the culture who wipes out civilizations who achieve certain technological levels.

Comment: What about this novel/series makes you think it's the right answer?

Comment: I read it and he described it. Multiple star-faring cultures, the impending invasion by the culture who wipes out civilizations who achieve certain technological levels. It's kind of hard to describe several thousand pages of story line in these answers. None of these authors are known for writing short novels and there are 8+  of them now.

Comment: If you can find a synopsis online that addresses some of the point in the question that would definitely improve your answer, for example, which book in the series is he likely to have read?