# Book series: Space Navy based Space Opera, several alien species warring for generations

Tags: story-identification, books, alien-invasion, space-colonization

There’s a series of books I read, probably 10 years or more ago that I just can’t seem to pinpoint.

Here are some things I recall:

1. Space Navy based Space Opera
2. Space ships could jump between solar systems through natural gateways and the edge of the solar system
3. Series covered wars and battles with several alien species across generations.
4. 1 Alien was a big spider-like creature that they couldn’t communicate with, it ate humans
5. 1 Alien was a big green humanoid in a massive ship without FTL capability that travelled between stars . They occupied a few worlds with humans rebelling against them. They were religious, reminded me of Hinduism.

Comment: Sounds vaguely *Babylon 5*-ish, although that's a TV series. (Space navy, tick. Jump gates between solar systems, tick. Wars and battles with several alien species across generations, tick. Big scary spider-like aliens, tick. Mysterious green aliens in massive ships, tick.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks to be the [Starfire](https://www.goodreads.com/series/41767-starfire) series by [David Weber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Weber)

The battle tactics in all are centred around attacking/defending jump points. 
The spiders appear the third book in the series (In Death Ground) and the fourth (The Shiva Option)

Comment: That is it ... thank you very much, I'm going to read them again for sure